# gender related translations with transchoice and lingohub

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

I have been trying to find a solution for this but have not found the answer that works for me. Basically what I want are gender specific translations in Symfony2 using twig and the service [lingohub](https://lingohub.com).

Our translations files (XLIFF format) for English look like this:

```
<trans-unit id="1234" resname="some_key">
  <source xml:lang="en">My text goes here </source>
  <target xml:lang="en">My text goes here </target>
</trans-unit>
```

for another language it would look like this:

```
<trans-unit id="2345" resname="some_key">
  <source xml:lang="en">My text goes here </source>
  <target xml:lang="es">My text in Spanish goes here</target>
</trans-unit>
```

what I now want is a gender specific translation.
I would love to use transchoice and use the translations from my files

On the [Symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html) I can only find the example with static text.

Question is what do I have to put in twig and what into the translations files?

I tried to put the choices in twig but then it does not translate at all.
I also tried to put one key and the choices in the translation file but this also does not work. It selects always the second option and also prints the text as it is (including {f} for female)

What I want is something like:

```
{% transchoice gender with {'%lastname%': user.lastname}  %}
  {f} key_for_female |{m} key_for_male | {u} key_for_unknown
{% endtranschoice %}
```

which will be replaced by translations like

```
<trans-unit id="1234" resname="key_for_female">
  <source xml:lang="en">Hello Ms %lastname% </source>
  <target xml:lang="en">Hello Ms %lastname%  </target>
</trans-unit>
```

so that the output is in the end "Hello Ms Doe". What is the correct syntax? ;)

Comment: Maybe the bundle could help: https://github.com/webfactory/icu-translation-bundle

Comment: I found an easy workaround with normal translation. I define a new variable in twig with an existing key from a different trans domain that we had already and use this variable. Example: {% set salutation =  (user.gender) | trans({}, 'user_gender')%}; user_gender is hereby the key that is translated as normal (e.g. 'f' would resolve to Ms).

Comment: Nice, make answer and accept it to help others.

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy workaround with normal translation. I define a new variable in twig with an existing key from a different trans domain that we had already and use this variable. Example:

```
{% set salutation = (user.gender) | trans({}, 'user_gender')%};
```

user_gender is hereby the key that is translated as normal (e.g. 'f' would resolve to Ms).